# Check if data already exists in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Can anyone help me to check whether the data already exists in the database by displaying message in red color if the data already exists in the database.

I want to check if the `StaffID` already exists in the database, if it does, the user cannot create a new profile using that same `staffID`.

But I do not know how to do it. Can anyone help me to do the code to check whether the `staffID` already exists in the database or not?

Your help is much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
<table id="tblBasicInfo">
  <tr>
     <td style="width: 50%">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"><span style="color: red">*</span>Staff ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStaffID" class="chosen-select form-control col-sm-9" Width="100%" data-placeholder="Choose StaffID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStaffID_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
         </div>
      </td><tr/>
  <tr>
     <td style="width:50%">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"><span style="color: red">*</span> Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
             <asp:TextBox class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your First Name" id="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
       </div>
     </td>
     <td style="width: 50%">                                            
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"><span style="color: red">*</span> Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <asp:TextBox class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" id="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <span class="help-inline col-xs-12 col-sm-7" />
        </div>
     </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td style="width:50%">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"><span style="color: red">*</span> Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         <asp:TextBox class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" id="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <span class="help-inline col-xs-12 col-sm-7" />
        </div>
       </div>
   </td>
   <td style="width:50%">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"><span style="color: red">*</span> Mobile Phone</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <asp:TextBox class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile Phone Number" id="txtMobilePhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <span class="help-inline col-xs-12 col-sm-7" />
      </div>
     </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Aspx code

```
Protected Sub ddlStaffID_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try
        ErrMsg = "LoadDataGrid "
        attPage.SQLQuery = DC.Data_TechnicalProfile("1001", ddlStaffID.SelectedItem.Value)
        DS = DA.GetSQLDataset(attPage.SQLQuery)
        If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            txtFirstName.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ParticipantName").ToString
            txtEmail.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Email").ToString
            txtMobilePhone.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ContactNo").ToString
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        attPage.ErrorMessage = DA.GetErrorMessage(1, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name.ToString, ErrMsg, ex.Message.ToString, attPage.ActionPage)
        ShowError(attPage.ErrorHeader, attPage.ErrorMessage)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub LoadDropDownList()
    Try

        attPage.SQLQuery = DC.Data_TechnicalResource("2")
        DS = DA.GetSQLDataset(attPage.SQLQuery)
        attPage.ErrorMessage = "SearchStaffID "
        ddlStaffID.DataTextField = "StaffID"
        ddlStaffID.DataValueField = "ID"
        ddlStaffID.DataSource = DS.Tables(5)
        ddlStaffID.DataBind()
        ddlStaffID.Items.Insert(0, "")



    Catch ex As Exception
        attPage.ErrorMessage = DA.GetErrorMessage(1, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name.ToString, ErrMsg, ex.Message.ToString, attPage.ActionPage)
        ShowError(attPage.ErrorHeader, attPage.ErrorMessage)
    End Try
End Sub
```

SQL Query

```
IF @Action=101
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT StaffID AS [StaffID], ParticipantID AS [ID], ParticipantName AS [Name]
    FROM mstUser
    WHERE StatusID = '1' AND GroupID = '12'
    ORDER BY StaffID
END
```

Comment: *"Can anyone help me to check whether the data already exists in the database by displaying message in red color if the data already exists in the database"*. That's a complete non-sequitur. You don't check a database by displaying a method.  If you want to check whether data exists in a database then you query the database.  You then display a message based on the result of that query.  They are two completely independent things. If you don't know how yo query a database then you should start by learning that. If you do know then you already know how to check whether the data exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming StatusID is the primary key of mstUser
If all you need is to check the existence of a record then...

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
    Dim count As Integer
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From mstUser Where StatusID = @StatusID", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlStaffID.SelectedItem.Value
            cn.Open()
            count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
    If count > 0 Then 'Record exists
        'You red alert code here.
        'If showing the alert is the problem then that is another question
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Code as per @marc_s using If Exists.

```
Private Sub OPCode3()
    Dim Exists As Boolean
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("If Exists (Select * From mstUser Where StatusID = @StatusID) Select 1 Else Select 0;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlStaffID.SelectedItem.Value
            cn.Open()
            Exists = CBool(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
    If Exists Then 'Record exists
        'You red alert code here.
        'If showing the alert is the problem then that is another question
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Edited the code to reflect "Record exists". Changed = to >

Comment: Word of warning: `SELECT COUNT(*)` on a large table can take **a long time** to complete - it would be better to rewrite this check to use `IF EXISTS()` logic

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for the correction. If I understand correctly, the If Exist will return as soon as it finds a match and the Count(*) must always scan the entire table. Yes? If the record does not exist then the timing would be the same.

Comment: Exactly. So if your third row out of 100 million already matches the criteria, `IF EXISTS()` will stop and return "true", while `COUNT(*)` will go on and count the number of occurrences over all 100 million rows - even though you're really **not** interested in the actual count - just the question if (or not) at least one occurrence exists ....